# Adding Button to JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am appending a JLabel and JCombobox to a JPanel.This works fine.But when I add two more buttons to this,I cannot see those buttons.

Below is my code:

```
JPanel jPanel=new JPanel();
jPanel.setLayout(null);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome");                       
label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 13));          
jPanel.add(label);     
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(comboboxbean);
combo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(285, 20));
combo.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 13));          
jPanel.add(combo);           
startButton = new JButton("Start");
stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
startButton.addActionListener(this);
startButton.setActionCommand("enable");
jPanel.add(startButton);
stopButton.addActionListener(this);
stopButton.setActionCommand("enable");
jPanel.add(stopButton); 
Insets insets = jPanel.getInsets();              

Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
        label.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 30 + insets.top,
                     size.width, size.height);

Dimension size1 = combo.getPreferredSize();
     combo.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 65 + insets.top,
                     size1.width, size1.height);

Dimension size2 = startButton.getPreferredSize();
    startButton.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top,
                size2.width, size2.height);

Dimension size3 = stopButton.getPreferredSize();
     stopButton.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 130 + insets.top,
             size3.width, size3.height);        

frame.add(jPanel);  
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Finally I am adding the JPanel to a JFrame. I have set the layout as null for JPanel.
I cant find why the buttons are not displayed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the entire code, including the one where you add the label and combobox.

Comment: Don't use null layout, use an appropriate Layout Manager instead!

Comment: Dan I have posted the entire code now..

Comment: If you use layout as null then set the bounds(x, y, width, height) with some normal values like: (20, 20, 100, 20). Don't get the size from the preferred size.

Comment: Its fine now. Thanks everybody...

Comment: @vijay please post your fix as answer and accept it, or accept the answer from below that helped you...

Answer (score 2):

If the layout is null, it means that you have to use the `setBounds()` method to position the components you add to your `JPanel`. You are not currently doing that, so I think buttons are drawn whether outside of the `JPanel`, or below your `JComboBox`.
Anyway if you want your buttons at specifics positions you have to tell them, this will not be automatic like it is when using a `Layout` other than null.

Comment: Hi miNde, I have used setBounds() but I am not getting it.Please see the code now.