# Add JButton by pressing another JButton in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I am new to Java Development. I want to ask that is there any way that I can add a new JButton while user press one JButton?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465297/add-dynamic-buttons-to-jpanel-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. I suggest reading up on [Action Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). You could set one button's visibility to false and then make it visible like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        otherButton.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I have done it but I have another question that which layout can adjust each item automatically?

Comment: Well then, if this is your accepted answer, you should mark it as such. Then perhaps do some research on [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Afterwards, write some code and try to get something to work. If it isn't working and you can't figure out why, post another question, with your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame1
     */
    public NewJFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);

        pack();
    }                     
int button = 0;
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        JButton jButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton.setText("button " + (++button));
        jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton);

        this.revalidate();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJFrame1 frame = new NewJFrame1();
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by having a read through...

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to write an `ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

The trick here is dealing with the `LayoutManager`.  Some layouts, like `BorderLayout` can give you issues with dynamically adding new components.  Make sure you're using a `LayoutManager` which will update when new components are added to them (like `FlowLayout`, `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`)

After you've added a component to a container, you also need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you've updated, so that a layout and paint pass are scheduled and the UI can be updated based on your changes.  Remember, Swing is lazy, it will wait until you tell it that it needs to be updated.

Comment: Probably, but what's that got to do with the question?

Comment: Reduce the complexity of your issue. Focus solely on trying to understand how you can update the UI dynamically, this will give you a better foundation from which you can adapt the solution to other problems

Comment: *"If you can write the code then please help me!"* is beyond both the scope of the question you've asked and SO's broader functionality